# Prestashop - change product category in database

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to mass change product categories. I updated two tables in database: `ps_category_product` (changed old id_category) and `ps_products` (changed old id_category_default) but in BO product table and webshop I still see old category (home).

When I edit product, select tab associations I see that product is associated with my new caterogy. Only when I save the product by click save button I see that product in properly categories.

I compared two rows in database (product with changed category by mysql query and product changed in BO) and these two look identical.

What am I doing wrong? I was trying clean cache (delete cache/cachefs and smarty/compile), disable all cache options but with no result.

Comment: Check the `ps_product_shop` table aswell and change their default category (for specific shop ids if you have multistore enabled).

Comment: It was such simply...

Answer (score 0):

To change the category, the following queries must be executed:

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE  '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product SET id_category = NEW_ID_CATEGORY WHERE id_category = OLD_ID_CATEGORY');
Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE  '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_shop SET id_category_default = NEW_ID_CATEGORY WHERE id_category_default = OLD_ID_CATEGORY AND id_shop = ID_SHOP');
Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE  '._DB_PREFIX_.'product SET id_category_default = NEW_ID_CATEGORY WHERE id_category_default = OLD_ID_CATEGORY');
```

Regards