# Prestashop - Refresh cache after database changes

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I had to make some changes on the ps_product table of a Prestashop 1.6 store (id_tax_rules_group for example). However, these changes are not being reflected in the store itself. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make changes in `ps_product_shop`table as well.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087875/prestashop-change-product-category-in-database) is a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! do you know the reason for having 2 tables with duplicated content? performance related maybe?

Comment: It is used to differentiate products between multi shop. Check ps_product_shop table there is a `id_shop` field in it.

Comment: @notGeek I've asked myself the same thing on many occasions and I still don't have an answer :)